# Finding the min index in the array javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [];
let maxNum = 15;



function findMin(A, start, end){

  var result = Math.min.apply(null, myArray)
  console.log(result)

  return 0;
}
```

This function should find the index for the minimum value in Array A looking at all values starting at the index start and ending at the index end. This INCLUDES the numbers at start and end.

return the INDEX where the minimum occurs.

For example, if A = [3,2,1,6,4]
findMax(A, 0,4)  should return 2 since the minimum value is 1 and it occurs at position 2 in this array.

**How would I got about finding the index of the minimum number?**

(myArray randomly generates numbers in an array already, I just don't know how to find the index of the lowest number in the array)

Comment: Are you allowed to use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Comment: There a lot of ways to do it and a lot of content on the internet that talks about this. It seems you are starting to learn javascript, so I suggest you don't use the built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a combination of Math.min and spread syntax

```
const arr = [3,2,1,6,4]
const index = arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr))

console.log(index) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `indexOf()` of your minimum value.  Or you manually iterate through the array with `forEach` and remember both the minimum value and it's index.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods : - manual & js functions

1. JS Function :

   `return A.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, A));`
2. Manual:

   A loop through he array will be faster any time.

[image: Running time of different JS functions]

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for

```
var ary = [1,6,8,2,0,8,9]
 function findMin(A, start, end) {
   var finalAry = A.slice(start, end);
   var result = Math.min.apply(null, finalAry)
   return A.indexOf(result);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Array prototype [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the first index of a value in the array. First, you need to find the minimum value that is between the start index and the end index. That's why we used [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which returns a subarray.

Example of array `slice`.

```
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

console.log(animals.slice(1, 3));
// slice will return the items from index 1 to upto 3
// expected output: Array ["bison", "camel"]
```

Then all we have to do is to find the min value and return the `indexOf`.

```
function findMin(A, start, end){
  let minValue = Math.min.apply(A.slice(start, end))
  return A.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, A));
}

let A = [3,2,1,6,4]
console.log( findMin( A, 0, 4) )
```

We can also express the same function using the ES6 arrow function.

```
const findMin = (A, start, end) => A.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math, A))

let A = [3,2,1,6,4]
console.log( findMin( A, 0, 4) )
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how your answer solves the question.

Answer (score -1):

try this way.

```
let myArray = [5,3,4,1,9];
let maxNum = 15;

function findMin(A, start, end){

  let result = Math.min.apply(null, myArray)
  console.log(myArray.indexOf(result))
}

findMin(myArray, 0, myArray.length)
```